# Is Office- and Outlook Integration available in Alfresco community edition 5.0.x?

Tags: alfresco

I would like to use Outlook integration as well as Office integration in Alfresco **community edition** version **5.0.x**

I read:

- http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/Outlook-reqs.html
- http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/aos-prereqs.html

When reading the doc, it should be possible, is this correct?

P.s. I ran into troubles when trying the office integration, no preview available, not possible to open/save files and so on, so I'm wondering if I have a problem with the installation or misunderstood the doc)

Environement:

- Windows 7
- Office Professional 2010
- Download Alfresco from here: https://www.alfresco.com/alfresco-community-download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read carefully

> Alfresco One 5.0 has full support for Alfresco Outlook Integration

Alfresco One 5.0 is enterprise and not Community. If you don't see any modules at the community download page as well, then there isn't.

You can try the https://addons.alfresco.com or you can contact http://www.contezza.nl who has an Outlook integration.